# PhpStorm doesn't collapse tags inside Angular templates

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, ng-template

I have searched but couldn't find an answer so I'm sure other Angular developers experience the same pain.

PhpStorm doesn't recognize the html tags inside a `<script type="text/ng-template" id="editnode">` template and therefore I cant collapse anything inside it which can make life difficult for long pages.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: PhpStorm screenshot]

Comment: Create a new html and put your template into it. Then use ng-include="'myTemplate.html'' inside <script> tag.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but since they all little dialogbox templates i quite like them in one file, if there is no other solution I'll do that

Comment: I didn't understand why you are using your templates inside script tag?

Comment: lol, dont know either, it worked so far... I'll move them to seperate files, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code folding doesn't currently work in script templates; please follow [WEB-12164](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12164) for updates